# Node js receive multiple messages parameters undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, parameters, multer

I'm trying to upload 2 files to my node js server. I use multer to receive data from the request. This is my endpoint:

```
        app.post('/testFile', imageUpload.fields([{name:'image',maxCount:1},{name:'image2',maxcount:1}]), function(req, res, next){
        res.sendStatus(201);
    });
```

And this is where I have set up the multer:

```
var somevariable= multer({
storage: multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, callback) => {
    var x= req.body.x;
    var y= req.body.y;
    var path = `./resources/pics/${x}/${y}`;
    fs.mkdirsSync(path);
    callback(null, path);
  },
  filename: (req, file, callback) => {
    callback(null, file.originalname);
  }
})
});
```

And I have some strange behaviour. If I process the first image, I receive 'undefined' both x and y parameters. But if my process reach the second image, I can get the passed value in x and y variable. Can somebody explain to me why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

Please use `muster` like this.

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: 'destinationPath'
});
var upload = multer({
    storage: storage
}).any();
upload(req, res, function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return res.end('Error');
    } else {
        // your code goes here
    }
}
```